# Apache - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost

Tags: networking, server, firefox, apache2

Im not able to access my localhost server by firefox.
Im using apache, and ive tried to run the following commands

```
$ service apache2 status

 * apache2 is running

$ sudo service apache2 restart

 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]

$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep apache

tcp6       0      0 :::81                   :::*                    LISTEN  
2658/apache2
```

any help?

firefox displays this error message:

```
"Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web."
```

Comment: Are you connecting to `localhost` or `localhost:81`? Your server is listening on port 81.

Comment: both dont work.